# CronTab every 5 minutes reboot doesn't work

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I've put the command

```
*/5 * * * * root /sbin/shutdown -r now
```

Inside "sudo crontab -e" on a Raspberry Pi, which should reboot the raspberry pi every 5 minutes. But instead nothing happens.

I've looked in "/var/log/syslog" but all it says is

```
Sep 24 08:55:01 raspberrypi CRON[638]: (root) CMD (root /sbin/shutdown -r now)
Sep 24 08:55:01 raspberrypi CRON[634]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Hoping someone can help me!
Thanks, Jake.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a valid command, remove the "root".

Since you edited the root crontab `(sudo crontab -e)`, the command is already executed as a root.